# Python, Tkinter, Change of label color

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a simple way to change the color of a text in a button?

I use `button['text'] = 'input text here'` to change what the button text will be after the push. Does something similar exist for the change of color, `button['color'] = 'red'`?

Comment: Have you read any documentation? This is clearly documented in many places.

Answer (score 16):

Use the `foreground` option to set a color of the text in a button.
Example:

```
button.configure(foreground="red")
```

Comment: or you can use `fg` they're synoymous