# How do I change the colour of my button and label on Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

My task is to create a label and button on Tkinter. The button has to change the label, and I have to change the colour of the button and the label. I have changed the colour of the background but I can't figure out how to do the same for the label and button.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def change():
    print("change functon called")

def main():
    rootWindow = Tk()
    rootWindow.geometry('400x400')
    rootWindow.configure(bg="red")

    global Label
    label = ttk.Label( rootWindow, text="Hello World!" )
    label.pack()

    button1 = ttk.Button( rootWindow, text="Change Label",
                        command=change)
    button1.pack()

    rootWindow.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: do you know whether you are using a ttk Label or a tkinter Label? Have you read the documentation for the widget? Have you searched this site? There are many questions related to changing button attributes.

Answer (score 4):

So configuring a buttons colors is a bit different when using `tkinter` button VS a `ttk` style button.

For a tkinter button you would use the background = "color" argument like the following:

```
button1 = Button( rootWindow, text="Change Label",
                      background = 'black', foreground = "white", command=change)
```

For a `ttk` button you would configure the style and then use the `style = "style name"` argument like the following.

```
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("BW.TLabel", foreground="white", background="black")

buttonTTK = ttk.Button( rootWindow, text="TTK BUTTON",style = "BW.TLabel", command=change)
```

More information on `ttk` configs can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def change():
    print("change functon called")

def main():
    rootWindow = Tk()

    label = ttk.Label( rootWindow, text="Hello World!",
                       background = 'black', foreground = "white")
    label.pack()

    button1 = Button( rootWindow, text="Change Label",
                          background = 'black', foreground = "white", command=change)
    button1.pack()

    style = ttk.Style()
    style.configure("BW.TLabel", foreground="white", background="black")

    buttonTTK = ttk.Button( rootWindow, text="TTK BUTTON",style = "BW.TLabel", command=change)
    buttonTTK.pack()

    rootWindow.mainloop()

main()
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 10, I have run into the same problem, and have found a solution, although not a very satisfying one. The following will create a black button with white foreground type:

First define a custom button style based on the standard TButton style

```
mystyle = ttk.Style()
mystyle.configure('mycustom.TButton',background='black',foreground='white')
```

Then create the button using the new custom style

```
mybutton = ttk.Button(root,style='mycustom.Tbutton')
```

I say 'not very satisfying' because this only works if I have previously set the overall theme to 'default' as follows:

```
mystyle = ttk.Style()
mystyle.theme_use('default')
```

Using any of the other themes available on my system (winnative,clam,alt,classic,vista and xpnative) will change only the border to black, and leave the background grey.

Comment: This also worked for me, but you lose the nice-looking button and get an unpleasant looking square one.

Answer (score 0):

From

[Python, Tkinter, Change of label color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36520886/python-tkinter-change-of-label-color/36520978)

This will change the label color of a button:

`button1.configure(foreground="red")`

I assume the same approach can be used for the label.

Answer (score 0):

For a ttk button the primary issue with color control requires usage of ttk.Style() and theme_use. Themes alt/classic/default allow 3D/color button control.  See [Python: Changing ttk button color depending on current color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46583398/python-changing-ttk-button-color-depending-on-current-color) for a code example using configure and map for style.