# How to change ttk button background and foreground when hover it in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I'm trying to change `ttk.tkinter` button background to black and foreground colour to white when mouse is hover it. Have tried  `highlightbackground` and `activebackground` but doesn't yield the result I'm looking for.

[image: Desired button image]

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


root = tk.Tk()

style = ttk.Style(root)
#style.theme_use("clam")

style.configure('TButton', foreground="black", highlightthickness=5,
                highlightbackground='#3E4149', highlightforeground="white",
                activebackground="black")

btr = ttk.Button(root, text="TEST BUTTON")
btr.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display message when hovering over something with mouse cursor in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20399243/display-message-when-hovering-over-something-with-mouse-cursor-in-python) - well similar enough.

Answer (score 9):

ttk Button appearances are driven by themes (3D/Color-alt/classic/default, Color-clam). Not setting/others leaves buttons flat/grey and settings don't change things.
To make a ttk TButton change colors can be achieved using map. 3D appearance requires borderwidth.Only Classic forms an outer ring using highlight.
Similar answer see: [Python: Changing ttk button color depending on current color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46583398/python-changing-ttk-button-color-depending-on-current-color)

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
root = tk.Tk()
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use("classic")

style.map("C.TButton",
   foreground=[('!active', 'black'),('pressed', 'red'), ('active', 'white')],
    background=[ ('!active','grey75'),('pressed', 'green'), ('active', 'black')]
    )
btr = ttk.Button(root, text="TEST BUTTON", style="C.TButton")
btr.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='nsew');
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the map function with your style, as described here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


root = tk.Tk()

style = ttk.Style(root)
#style.theme_use("clam")


style.map("C.TButton",
    foreground=[('pressed', 'red'), ('active', 'blue')],
    background=[('pressed', '!disabled', 'black'), ('active', 'white')]
    )

btr = ttk.Button(root, text="TEST BUTTON", style="C.TButton")
btr.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Register the style map with the button.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't solve it, background colour should change but not border colour

Comment: Use `tk.Button` instead of `ttk.Button`, as the `tk.Button` supports greater button shape customization. Options listed in your Style config do not exist for the `ttk.Button` variant.

Comment: Seems like `ttk.Button` does not support changing background color.  If you can use `tk.Button`, then you can bind events `<Enter>` and `<Leave>` to change its foreground and background colors.

Answer (score 0):

you have to try this I was having this problem before I learned this Code

```
import tkinter 
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk


f=Tk()

style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("BW.TLabel", foreground="blue", 
background="red")

l1 = ttk.Label(f,text="Test", style="BW.TLabel")
l2 = ttk.Label(f,text="Test", style="BW.TLabel")
l1.pack()
l2.pack()
f.mainloop(
```

you must see this documentation in python.org website
[[it will learn you a lot of things like that I wrote[1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#ttkstyling)][1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#ttkstyling)

Comment: U used too many duplicates from import ttk