# Tkinter button color

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter

When I create a button like this in tkinter:

```
self.submition_button=Button(self.root, text='Submit', 
            font='Times 12 bold italic', command=self.onSubmition, bg='blue')
```

the button isn't blue.

Why isn't it blue, and what can I do to make it blue?

Comment: do you use `tkinter.Button` or `ttk.Button` ? They work differently. What system do you use? On some systems it  may not work.

Comment: Are you on OSX?

Comment: Bryan Oakley - yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using tkinter.Button or are you really using ttk.Button?
You'll know which one your using based on what you imported in the top of code

regular tkinter widgets importing

```
import tkinter
```

typical TTK widgets importing

```
from tkinter import ttk
```

Because `TTK` is more modern version of the library it's styling system is different. So setting flag options on it wont work. instead you have to use style theme.

See this reply.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44416355/8661716

Comment: I used tkinter.Button

Comment: Maybe because the button is too small so the background color is covered by the text?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for a blue button, check it :

```
from tkinter import *

#create a window
root =Tk()

button=Button(root, text='Submit',  font='Times 12 bold italic', bg='blue', activebackground="blue")
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```