# Setting background color or bg for a button in Python Tkinter not working

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to tkinter and I can't set the background color of a button

My code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root).grid(row = 0, column = 0)

button = ttk.Button(frame, text = "CLICK ME", bg = '#05752a').grid(row = 0, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

ERROR:

```
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-bg"
```

Comment: `button = Button(frame, text = "CLICK ME", bg = '#05752a').grid(row = 0, column = 0)` remove ttk from button

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44416355/2111778

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't an easy way to change the background of a button from the ttk library.

But you can easily get what you want with a normal tkinter. Button if you set the right options. Below is an example script:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root).grid(row = 0, column = 0)

button = Button(frame, text = "CLICK ME", bg = '#05752a').grid(row = 0, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

**This is the Link to another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27347981/how-to-change-the-color-of-ttk-button#:%7E:text=Add%20a%20comment-,15,rgb%20%3D%20(183%2C%20247%2C%2049)%0A%3E%3E%3E%20%27%23%7B%3A02x%7D%7B%3A02x%7D%7B%3A02x%7D%27.format(*rgb)%0A%27%23b7f731%27,-%3E%3E%3E)**

Comment: _"there isn't an easy way to change the background of a button from the ttk library"_ - that's not entirely true. You can create custom styles and apply the styles to the frame, and it only takes a few lines of code.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes, You're Right But This way is easy than creating a custom style in ttk.